# como agregar columnas a un Jpanel en java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola estoy intentando añadir columnas a un Panel creado en un formulario pero no me reconoce el metodo `setModel()`.
mi Panel se llama "tablaCompra".

```
public class registroDeVenta extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
      * Creates new form registroDeVenta.
      */

    public registroDeVenta() {
        initComponente();
        this.tablaCombra.setModel(modelo);
        this.modelo.addColumn("Proyecto");
        this.modelo.addColumn("Precio");
        this.modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");
        this.modelo.addColumn("IGV");
        this.modelo.addColumn("Importe Total");
    }
DefaultTableModel modelo= new DefaultTableModel();
```

Comment: creo que hay que quitarle el this.tablaCompra, y dejarlo solo como tablaCompra. Tendrías que mostrar como declaras tablaCompra y también donde la declaras, dentro o fuera del JFrame, para poder entender mejor

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haría así:

```
public class registroDeVenta extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   public registroDeVenta() {
        initComponente();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JTable table = new JTable();
        // tiene una fila nula para que se vean los titulos, solo eliminas el null
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {null},
            new String[] { "Proyecto", "Precio", "Cantidad", "IGV", "Importe Total" }));  

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
```

las jTables es mejor agregarlas sobre un scrollPane